# Gmail label request fails with http 403 (forbidden)

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

I have an application that uses OAuth 2 to access Gmail.  This is working fine for most users.  For some users, however, my application fails at the point of trying to read the Gmail labels, with http error 403 (forbidden).  Keep in mind that previous to this API call, I have accessed the user profile successfully.  Here is the call that fails:

```
GET /gmail/v1/users/user.name@domain.com/labels?access_token=ya29.fwI_zL1rF3xOIQcHNzpBhmjVlJhRpofkh4a9mVvwhYRo6H09qX5RNKv76zKT7e6-sEZr
```

I am requesting the following scopes when getting the access token, and the user has logged in to Google and accepted the request for access (and I can see this when we look at his security dashboard):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels
https://mail.google.com/
```

Note that I just added the gmail.labels scope in at attempt to fix this.
Again, this code is working fine for most users - why do some users fail the label request?

Comment: Are you aware of that a Google `access token` has a lifespan of one hour before it becomes invalid?

Comment: Yes I am quite aware of that.  I am making the label access call within milliseconds of obtaining the token (via a refresh token).

Comment: Great :) Maybe some tokens contain characters not allowed in a URL parameter? Maybe you have to URL encode it first.

Comment: Also, you can try the shorthand `me` instead of `user.name@domain.com` which will work in every case.

Comment: What is the error detail (it's in the HTTP body)?

Comment: I tried using "me" instead of the user email and was shocked to find that it seems to fix my problem.  Can you explain why?  Is it the period in the email address?  Now I'm having the same issue with OAuth 2 in IMAP, but there is no opportunity there to use "me".

Comment: @JeffMcKay I'm not sure, to be honest. Maybe the `@` is posing a problem? I have always used `me`. Maybe you could try the url encoded `@` => `%40`

Answer (score 0):

Use the shorthand value `me` instead of `user.name@domain.com` and the user who the `access token` belongs to will be used automatically.